# Restricted Cubic Spline-RCSPLINE macro

Tags: sas, splines

I have to manually create basis functions for a variable but SAS doesn't seem to have a procedure to do it.  I am using Frank Harrell's macro RCSPLINE but the basis variables are not identical to those created by SAS.  It seems like SAS is dividing the second basis by 4 and the last one by 4.5.  Not sure where these numbers come from for the example  given below.  Why are SAS numbers different from the ones created by the macro?

```
data simulation;
  do i=1 to 10000;
  t=rand('uniform',0,10);
  p=1/(1+exp(sin(t)));
  y=rand('bernoulli',p);
  output;
  end;
run;

*model a natural cubic spline;
*and store the result in "mystore";
proc logistic data=simulation OUTDESIGN=splines;
  effect myspline=spline(t/knotmethod=list(1,2,3,4) NATURALCUBIC);
  model y(event="1")=myspline;
  store mystore;
run;
/*-------------------------
   MACRO FOR CUBIC SPLINES
  -------------------------*/
%macro rcspline(x,knot1,knot2,knot3,knot4,knot5,knot6,knot7,knot8,knot9,knot10, norm=2);
%LOCAL j v7 k tk tk1 t k1 k2;
%LET v7=&x; %IF %length(&v7)=8 %THEN %LET v7=%SUBSTR(&v7,1,7);
  %*get no. knots, last knot, next to last knot;
    %DO k=1 %TO 10;
    %IF %QUOTE(&&knot&k)=  %THEN %GOTO nomorek;
    %END;
%LET k=11;
%nomorek: %LET k=%EVAL(&k-1); %LET k1=%EVAL(&k-1); %LET k2=%EVAL(&k-2);
%IF &k<3 %THEN %PUT ERROR: <3 knots given.  no spline variables CREATEd.;
%ELSE %DO;
 %LET tk=&&knot&k;
 %LET tk1=&&knot&k1;
 DROP _kd_; _kd_=
 %IF &norm=0 %THEN 1;
 %ELSE %IF &norm=1 %THEN &tk - &tk1;
 %ELSE (&tk - &knot1)**.666666666666; ;
    %DO j=1 %TO &k2;
    %LET t=&&knot&j;
    &v7&j=max((&x-&t)/_kd_,0)**3+((&tk1-&t)*max((&x-&tk)/_kd_,0)**3
        -(&tk-&t)*max((&x-&tk1)/_kd_,0)**3)/(&tk-&tk1)%STR(;);
    %END;
 %END;
%mend rcspline;

**comparing to splines datasets from PROC LOGISTIC
**t1 from PROC LOGISTIC=t1 from below divided by 4-1=3;
DATA want; SET simulation;
%rcspline(t,1,2,3,4); 
RUN;
```

Comment: I no longer have SAS, so I can't try things out, but this paper by Rick Wicklin may be useful:
https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/02/18/regression-restricted-cubic-splines-sas.html

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was helpful.  It is different.  A copy and paste from the site. One last comment: the basis functions that are generated by the EFFECT statement are not equal to the basis functions created by the %RCSPLINE macro, but they are equivalent. The EFFECT statement uses the definition from The Elements of Statistical Learning (Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman, 2009, 2nd Ed, pp. 144-146). The %RCSPLINE macro implements scaled versions of the basis function. Thus parameter estimates will be different but the predicted values will be the same.